# assign value using linq

Tags: c#, linq

```
public class Company
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
}

List<Company> listofCompany = new List<Company>();
```

this is my collection of company list I want to assign values to Name property using LINQ

```
listofCompany.Where(d => d.Id = 1);
```

(I want to assing name property of company id 1)

how do I assign it.?

Answer (score 135, accepted):

using **Linq** would be:

```
 listOfCompany.Where(c=> c.id == 1).FirstOrDefault().Name = "Whatever Name";
```

**UPDATE**

This can be simplified to be...

```
 listOfCompany.FirstOrDefault(c=> c.id == 1).Name = "Whatever Name";
```

---

### UPDATE

For multiple items (condition is met by multiple items):

```
 listOfCompany.Where(c=> c.id == 1).ToList().ForEach(cc => cc.Name = "Whatever Name");
```

Comment: how we can achieve following query for multiple elements listOfCompany.Where(c=> c.id == 1).FirstOrDefault().Name = "Whatever Name";

Comment: You can shorten your first example to `listOfCompany.FirstOrDefault(c=> c.id == 1).Name = "Whatever Name";`

Comment: This is actually very useful. I was wondering how you can set more than one variable value at a time. My object has actually two variables I need to set in one pass.

Comment: how about the null check?

Comment: .FirstOrDefault() will throw NullReferenceException if no elements match Where

Answer (score 8):

You can create a extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Do<T>(this IEnumerable<T> self, Action<T> action) {
    foreach(var item in self) {
        action(item);
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

And then use it in code:

```
listofCompany.Do(d=>d.Id = 1);
listofCompany.Where(d=>d.Name.Contains("Inc")).Do(d=>d.Id = 1);
```

Comment: BTW: Argument 1: cannot convert from `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>` to `T`

Answer (score 3):

It can be done this way as well

```
foreach (Company company in listofCompany.Where(d => d.Id = 1)).ToList())
                {
                    //do your stuff here
                    company.Id= 2;
                    company.Name= "Sample"
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that it only updates the first company it found with company id 1. For multiple

```
 (from c in listOfCompany where c.id == 1 select c).First().Name = "Whatever Name";
```

For Multiple updates

```
 from c in listOfCompany where c.id == 1 select c => {c.Name = "Whatever Name";  return c;}
```