# How to assign values to a list by linq without for or foreach statements?

Tags: c#, linq

I want to compare two lists and assign 1st list to another in case of requirement.

```
var getdetail=_readonlyservice.getdetail().ToList();
foreach(var item in docdetail)
{
      var temp=getdetail.firstordefualt(i=>i.Id=item.Id)
      if(temp==null) continue;
      item.code=temp.code;
}
```

I want to implement top statements in linq .any help ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376405/assign-value-using-linq

Comment: My question A little different

Answer (score 1):

Think so..

```
var getdetail=_readonlyservice.getdetail().ToList();
var tempList = from dd in context.docdetail
                join g in context.getdetail on dd.Id equals g.Id
               select new // Your type
               {
                 // Columns...
                 Code = g.Code
               }
```

Comment: how to implement your code by where or foreach  statement ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are trying to do like the way I did, although I was going to join table.

```
var result = (from e in DSE.employees
             join d in DSE.departments on e.department_id equals d.department_id
             join ws in DSE.workingshifts on e.shift_id equals ws.shift_id
                              select new
                              {
                                  FirstName = e.FirstName,
                                  LastName = e.LastName,
                                  Gender = e.Gender,
                                  Salary = e.Salary,
                                  Department_id = e.department_id,
                                  Department_Name = d.department_name,
                                  Shift_id = ws.shift_id,
                                  Duration = ws.duration,
                              }).ToList();
                // TODO utilize the above result
```

I was using DTO method to do this. And then you return result(as this case is result).
You may view the whole question and solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60406692/c-sharp-web-api-inner-join-and-return-query-value/).

As this case, you are not required to put foreach loop, as the query said from **every row** in **yourdatabase.table**