# How do I assign properties in a collection using LINQ (en masse)

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have an array or collection of (class) type `Foo` with a property `Value` of type `double`. If I have a list of values, how do I assign them to my collection using LINQ.

Essentially I want the reverse of

```
var values = list.Select((item)=>item.Value).ToArray();
```

Example Code:

```
class Foo
{
    public double Value { get; set; }
    // many other properties
}

static void Main() 
{
    // example initializations
    var list = new Foo[4];

    // somewhere else in the code
    var values = GetValues();
    // returns { 10.0, 12.0, 15.5, 17.3 }

    // Q? Can I do this in LINQ with one statement,
    // without re-creating list. I just want to set
    // one property of Foo based on my array.

    // assign values (I know lengths will match)
    for(int i=0; i<list.Length; i++)
    {
        list[i].Value = values[i];
    }

}
```

I tried this (and failed):

```
list.Zip(values, (leg, val) => leg.Value=val );
```

But this works, although it feels like a kludge

```
list.Zip(values, (leg, val) => leg.Value=val ).ToArray();
```

PS. This is similar to [assign value using linq](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5376405/380384) except that I want to assign all the values in my list, and not just filter one and get a reference to it.

PS2. What if `Foo` is a value type, would this be harder.

FYI. In `Fortran` you would do `list%value = values` even though `list` is an array. In Fortran an array of structures is equivalently also a structure of arrays. I wish other languages (Python,Julia?) also did the same. The `C` type languages do not though :-(

Comment: LINQ is generally functional, it expresses a query. You would not usually expect a LINQ query to have side effects. Personally, I'd stick with some sort of loop.

Comment: Your scientists were so preoccupied with whether or not they could, they didn’t stop to think if they should...  Dr. Ian Malcolm - Jurassic Park

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it's good that you're using `Zip` to pair up the items you want to update with the values you want to inject, but that's all you should be doing with that.  Once you paired them up, you should loop over the pairs to do the update.

```
var pairs = list.Zip(values, (leg, val) => new { leg, val });
foreach (var pair in pairs)
    pair.leg.Value = pair.val;
```

Linq is designed to help you query data, not modify it.

Comment: Best use of Linq so far.  The way it was intended.

Comment: This is clear as it shows intent better than a `Zip` statement that does not return a value. Also it seems with deferred execution only one loop is really executed.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a LINQ like extension method, this does not return a `IEnumerable` but modifies the `IEnumerable` (or `IList` for structs) that is being passed in.

```
public static class ExtentionMethods
{
    public static void Update<TItem, TValue>(this IEnumerable<TItem> @this, IEnumerable<TValue> items, Action<TItem, TValue> applyAction) 
        where TItem : class
    {
        using (var thisEnumerator = @this.GetEnumerator())
        using (var itemEnumerator = items.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (thisEnumerator.MoveNext() && itemEnumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                applyAction(thisEnumerator.Current, itemEnumerator.Current);
            }
        }
    }

    public delegate void UpdateAction<TItem, TValue>(ref TItem item, TValue newValue);

    public static void Update<TItem, TValue>(this IList<TItem> @this, IEnumerable<TValue> items, UpdateAction<TItem, TValue> applyAction)
where TItem : struct 
    {

        using (var itemEnumerator = items.GetEnumerator())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < @this.Count && itemEnumerator.MoveNext(); i++)
            {
                var temp = @this[i];
                applyAction(ref temp, itemEnumerator.Current);
                @this[i] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

used like

```
namespace SandboxConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        class Foo
        {
            public double Value { get; set; }
        }
        struct Foo2
        {
            public double Value { get; set; }
        }

        private static IReadOnlyList<double> GetValues()
        {
            return new[] { 10.0, 12.0, 15.5, 17.3 };
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            // example initializations
            var list = new Foo[4];
            var list2 = new Foo2[4];

            // somewhere else in the code
            var values = GetValues();
            // returns { 10.0, 12.0, 15.5, 17.3 }

            list.Update(values, (item, value) => item.Value = value);
            list2.Update(values, (ref Foo2 item, double value) => item.Value = value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To the person who downvoted, please let me know what you find unhelpful about my answer. The op is not looking for a actual LINQ solution because he does not care about the result of `list.Zip(values, (leg, val) => leg.Value=val ).ToArray();` in his example, he just wants a single line extension method that can do the action that will work that is not as verbose as `list.Zip(values, (leg, val) => leg.Value=val ).ToArray();`

Comment: I think it might be the OP that's downvoting them all.. Bit of a rum deal though, to ask a question that conceptually has no sensible answer, and then downvote everyone who comes up with a hacky kludge that makes for a nonsensible answer

Comment: @CaiusJard The morale of the story thus being to not try to post answers to questions that don't have a sensible answer, no?

Comment: @Servy I thought my answer was sensable. All it is really doing is collapsing his existing foreach in to a extension method.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I don't see any advantages of it over simply using a loop.  It's less bad than the other answers here, but it's still not actually adding any real value, and it does still have some costs.

Answer (score -2):

This:

```
var list = values.Select(item =>new Foo{Value=item}).ToArray();
```

Same as:

```
for(int i=0; i<list.Length; i++)
{
  list[i].Value = values[i];
}
```

Comment: To clarify things I edited the question. I do not want to recreate `Foo`. So no `new Foo()` statements. I want to assign values or a single property of `Foo`.

Comment: Then your best bet is to use a for or foreach loop. To implement a foreach you can var list = values.Select((v,i) => new{Value=v, Index =i})

Answer (score -3):

You can use ForEach on a List

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] x = { 1, 2, 3 };
        Foo[] y = new Foo[]{ new Foo{Name="a"},new Foo{Name="b"},new Foo{Name="c"}};

        int i = 0;
        y.ToList().ForEach(a => a.Value = x[i++]);

        foreach (Foo f in y) 
          Console.Out.WriteLine(f.ToString());

        //or even ;)
        y.ToList().ForEach(a => Console.Out.WriteLine(a.ToString));
    }
}
class Foo
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name + Value;
    }
}
```

I can't think of a way to ditch the `int i = 0` line right now

But consider the arguments raised in https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/ if you do?

Edit: OK, so someone took issue with it not being LINQ (the ToList() is). Do this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] x = { 1, 2, 3 };
        Foo[] y = new Foo[]{ new Foo{Name="a"},new Foo{Name="b"},new Foo{Name="c"}};

        int i = 0;
        y.Select(a => a.Value = x[i++]).ToArray();

        foreach (Foo f in y) 
          Console.Out.WriteLine(f.ToString());
    }
}
class Foo
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name + Value;
    }
}
```

The Select is LINQ, the ToArray makes the action actually happen by the time the loop prints the values.. It's not the intended purpose of a querying system though

Tall and short of it is:

Q: "How do I ..."

A: You don't

A: You use fortran

A: You write a foreach loop, like anyone else who is interested in generating readable, self explanatory, maintainable code

Comment: That's not using LINQ