# Assign multiple values using linq

Tags: c#, linq

Please, refer to this other post: [assign value using linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376405/assign-value-using-linq)

With this expression we can update one value in multiple items of a list:

```
listOfCompany.Where(c=> c.id == 1).ToList().ForEach(cc => cc.Name = "Whatever Name");
```

Is it possible to update more than one value? Is this more efficient that implementing a foreach structure and set the multiple values in it?

Comment: *Is this more efficient that implementing a foreach structure*
I would say no. Creating a `List` first (which already enumerates the collection) only to use its `ForEach` method, is not more efficient than doing a foreach directly on the enumeration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use brackets:

```
listOfCompany.Where(c=> c.id == 1).ToList().ForEach(cc => 
{    
    cc.Name = "Whatever Name";
    cc.Name = "Whatever Name";
    cc.Name = "Whatever Name";
});
```

Or use a ref to a method:

```
listOfCompany.Where(c=> c.id == 1).ToList().ForEach(UpdateCompany);

private void Function(Company cc) 
{    
    cc.Name = "Whatever Name";
    cc.Name = "Whatever Name";
    cc.Name = "Whatever Name";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
listOfCompany.Where(c=> c.id == 1).ToList().ForEach(cc =>
{ 
    cc.Name = "Whatever Name";
    cc.OtherField="Whatever field";
});
```

Answer (score 2):

LINQ is fun and all, but IMHO you should try to go for readable and *maintainable* code. When you need to update several fields I would argue that a regular `foreach` would suit you better.

```
foreach(var item in listOfCompany.Where(c=> c.id == 1))
{
    item.Name = "Whatever Name";
    item.Property = 1;
    //..
}
```

As for if it's more efficient, I don't think you would notice it. You can always study the [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,03061465caeb91cc) - it's basically only calling an `Action` for each item.

Comment: I second the *maintainable* hint. Regretted every single time when I thought I should do some smartass linq inline assignment. That being said, I found some of my legacy code, where I used `Zip` to merge-assign a collection of values into a collection of items. *In retrospect, code older than a year looks like shit*

Answer (score 0):

Approach without `ForEach` and only one iteration instead of two

```
listOfCompany = listOfCompany.Select(x => { 
                              x.Name = x.id == 1 ? "Whatever Name" : x.Name; 
                              x.Name2 = x.id == 1 ? "Whatever Name" : x.Name2;   
                              return x; 
                              }).ToList();
```

---

Approach without Linq (probably the fastes one)

```
for (int i = 0; i < listOfCompany.Count; i++)
{
    if (listOfCompany[i].id == 1)
    {
        listOfCompany[i].Name = "Whatever Name";
        listOfCompany[i].Name2 = "Whatever Name";
    }
}
```

Comment: It's probably worth noting that this goes against the spirit of LINQ...

Comment: @JonSkeet imo it's prettier and faster compared to `.Where().ToList().ForEach()`

Comment: It's very easy to make mistakes with it though - e.g. someone thinking "Hang on, I don't need a new list... I'll just take out the assignment and the `ToList` call" at which point it doesn't do anything due to lazy evaluation. Simply using a `foreach` loop is the clearest approach IMO.

Answer (score 0):

try code 
Just use { }  and Every item End use ; semicolon

```
listOfCompany.Where(c=> c.id == 1).ToList().ForEach(cc => { cc.Name = "Whatever Name";cc.Contacts="Manager";});
```